Ubuntu 24.04 unable to upgrade to 24.04.1
If I make do-release-upgrade nothing happens...
And if I run apt ugrade, some stuff updates, but it stays 24.04 ...

The do-release-upgrade command will change release; you just need to apply all security fixes and your 24.04 system will upgrade to 24.04.1 (if you hadn't already; installed systems upgraded in the week before release of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS as the release was new installation media only).   The release is 24.04 and that will not change (.1 relates mostly to ISO)

Also note that some sources (largely 3rd party; or when using a development release) are added to a system, you may need to use apt full-upgrade to apply all fixes, and not just apt upgrade.  If you need help on that command, just read the man upgrade detail, or search on this site for comparisons between apt upgrade and apt dist-upgrade or apt full-upgrade...

This looks like an XY Question. The OP actually has a question about mutter versions.

Ubuntu 24.04.1 is the compilation of all upgrades released since 24.04, packaged in a single ISO.
If you are on 24.04, and perform all available upgrades with
sudo apt full-upgrade

then don't have to worry about anything else. The system may not show 24.04.1.

yeah but mutter --version
mutter 46.0
it should be: 46.2

@AleksandarPavić Open Software & Sources, and enable noble-updates. Then perform all available updates

Eventually I was able to upgrade but when I specifically enabled "noble proposed" under Developer Options...
